# Extracting RID from Windows SID

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sid

I use `ldap_get_values_len()` function to get binary data for Windows `objectSid` attribute that is part of user data in AD DS. I need to convert Windows SID to Unix UID number for authentication purposes.

The way I understand SID format is that the last 4 bytes of it is the RID, which is different for each user/group within a domain. The plan is to simply extract these last 4 bytes, convert from little endian to host native byte order and use the value for UID number.

So assuming I'm always using AD DS and not AD LDS (which has a different SID/RID format). Can anyone suggest any reason why this may not always work, or any other problems I have not thought of?

Comment: This link has a lot of information you may want to consider: http://pig.made-it.com/uidgid.html

Comment: Right, running into a similar question in the past, the thread about [Get SID by its objectSid using ldapsearch](https://serverfault.com/a/852338/448950) helped me to answer my questions. It is working almost and I wasn't running into any painful issues. The only thing I've noticed is, that large UIDs, 8-10 digits, let [lastlog file size increase](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=771286).